# How do I add a file browser inside my Java application?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, file-handling

I am new to Java progamming and am building a application that will add, display and remove files from a given folder location.

I have added files using JFileChooser and know how to delete the files. However I am stuck with the display portion.

I want to display the files and folder using different icon inside my application. I tried to add a JFileChooser inside the display panel and disable the button and menu components of the dialog box, but I have not succeeded. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

I prefer the following way.

```
JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();

int choice = choose.showOpenDialog();

if (choice != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;

File chosenFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

// You can then do whatever you want with the file.
```

Calling this code will cause a `JFileChooser` to popup in its own window.

I usually call it from within a `JButton`'s `ActionListener` code.

```
fileChooseButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        // File chooser code goes here usually
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done this and successfully, i used JFileChooser's open dialog box and copied the selected file to a folder. Now i need to display the content of that file inside a panel. Like explorer or file browser view. I can add openDialog or other dialog using JfileChooser, the only problem there would be of extra buttons. How do i disable them(top menu, button for new folder and so on) other then the file and folder view.   
Thank you

Comment: I would recommend asking that question as another question.  It would be much more helpful to others there.

Comment: Besides, the question and answer editors offer tons more formatting options.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need all the flexibility of `JFileChooser`, you should use `java.awt.FileDialog` instead.  Your OS X users will thank you.  `FileDialog` uses a native file chooser window, while `JFileChooser` is a swing component, and lacks keyboard shortcuts and other niceties.

Comment: Yeah, the swing dialog on os x is plain ugly. :/

Answer (score 1):

I've never fully replicated a file browser. I have displayed files in list/tables using the icon that is provided by your platform. This is rather easy to do with the help of [FileSystemView](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html). Use the getSystemIcon(File) method to retrieve the correct icon. Then you can build a JList/JTable of files using this icon.