# How to open files in Java Swing without JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, file-io, swt, jfilechooser

I'm using Java Swing (GUI) and I want to add a button to my project for opening files.

I don't like the `JFileChooser` since it opens a small window for browsing through the files of the directories. Can I use something else instead of the `JFileChooser` **under Java Swing**?

I've tried to use elements of SWT but it didn't work, meaning is the use of the button object and then use it inside the `JFrame`, but that failed, so I guess SWT and Swing don't mix together?

Here is the example of [Java Swing with JFileChooser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm)  and I'm looking for something [like this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FileDialogExample.htm) to put in my `JFrame`.

[image: Windows file dialog]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JFileChooser` with the native PLAF seems to fulfill the stated requirement.

[image: Native PLAF file chooser]

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class NativeFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
                jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Still not quite to your liking?  Then you might start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui) & change it to need:

[image]

---

> ..so I guess SWT and Swing don't mix together?

It is generally not a good idea to mix Swing/AWT/SWT components in the **same top-level container**.  It is not a problem to open an AWT `FileDialog` over a Swing based `JFrame` since they are both top-level containers.  I am pretty sure the same would apply to Swing/SWT or AWT/SWT.

Comment: How can I use this code without the `main` ? I've tried to remove this but the code won't compile without it . Thanks !!

Comment: *"How can I use this code without the main?"*  Unless you have a tricky IDE that inserts a default (invisible) `main` method for you, it is necessary to either have at least one `main` or develop an applet, to get a Swing GUI on-screen.  I don't recommend the applet, so stick with understanding how to get code to work from a `main`.

Comment: I need to pick a file and then parse it , in short , the process of choosing the file is only the beginning of the program , hence the `main` makes it difficult . Should I post the entire code in another question ? thank again .

Comment: *"..post the entire code in another question.."*  1) Yes, another question, but 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (rather than the 'entire code').

Comment: FYI: That works on Windows, but not on OS X. Under OS X the `FileDialog` shows the standard 'Open file' window (including a sidebar) while the `JFileChooser` does not have a side bar. And I am afraid that under Linux you end up with the GTK `JFileChooser` which is quite frankly un-usable and has nothing in common with a decent file chooser

Comment: @Robin *"That works on Windows, but not on OS X."*  Define 'works'.  I would not try to foist a Windows style file chooser on the OS X users.  My experiences with the GTK chooser are from a while ago & I'm a bit hazy, maybe offering the user whatever PLAF they want would be best.  They might prefer the Nimbus style file chooser.  It is a pity that the AWT `FileDialog` is not more powerful/configurable.

Comment: I mean that the native Look-and-feel (=Aqua) `JFileChooser` on OS X is not the same as the standard 'Open a file' dialog you get in the standard OS X applications. The `FileDialog` on the other hand looks the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need the flexibility of the `JFileChooser`, you can opt for the `FileDialog` which uses the native OS file dialog. See also [Code ranch topic](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345134/GUI/java/FileDialog-JFileChooser) and [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/798287/1076463)

Comment: @ron Yes you can. Otherwise I would not have suggested it

Comment: Basically ,SWT & Swing , mix together ?

Comment: @ron No, but AWT and Swing is possible