# Use JFileChooser without using a main declaration

Tags: java, swing, file-io, swt, jfilechooser

Following my previous post [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900696/how-to-open-files-in-java-swing-without-jfilechooser/10901164#10901164) I have another problem .

Given the following code :

```
public class GuiHandler extends javax.swing.JFrame {

// GuiHandler is the class that runs the entire project 
// here are two private fields that I use in the code , I have more but they
// irrelevant for the moment 

final JFileChooser openFiles = new JFileChooser();
private DataParser xmlParser = new DataParser();


// later on I have this method - XMLfilesBrowserActionPerformed


private void XMLfilesBrowserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

       //setting the file chooser
    openFiles.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    openFiles.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (openFiles.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //getting the selected file
        File selected = openFiles.getSelectedFile();

// from here I parse the XML file that I opened with JFileChooser 
// with the help of one of my methods getNodeListFromFile
xmlParser.getNodeListFromFile(selected);
```

The problem is that I cannot use the declaration of `main` that was suggested before in the link above (and I must add that was a pretty nice one:)), the code that was posted is :

```
public class NativeFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
                jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the use of `main` makes it very difficult for manipulating the `XML` file later on  ,with my 
method `getNodeListFromFile` .

What I need is to use the "simple" browser of `JFileChooser` , and then use the chosen file , without involving the `main` into that .

I'd appreciate if someone can explain how can I use the above code (or anything else) with my code .

Best regards

**EDIT:**

If I use the code like this ;

```
  public void launchFileChooser() {

     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            if (jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                 newFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();

        }
    });

  }
```

here `newFile` is a data member .

then after opening the file , the code crashes .

If I make `jfc` a data member , the code opens the regular browser . Any idea how to fix it ?

thanks

Comment: 1) A GUI class should typically not extend `JFrame` instead the code should just retain an instance of one.  2) The frame in the code shown in the accepted answer will be Metal PLAF (it is created before the PLAF is changed), which might look odd in your application. 3) What is the use-case here?  It seems you want a `JFileChooser` to appear before the main GUI, and that the main GUI will never need to open a 2nd XML.  Is that right?  4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as I posted, and as alluded to by akf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that code was simply a self contained example.

You should work the `JFileChooser` into your `GuiHandler` somehow.  If anything, you could add that code to an init method of your `GuiHandler`

```
public class GuiHandler extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  //lots of your other code
  public void launchFileChooser() {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     GuiHandler handler = new GuiHandler();
     handler.launchFileChooser();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Is there a way to make the browser to show only `.xml` files ?

Comment: You can create a subclass of `FileFilter` and take care of it yourself.  Take a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters

Comment: it is best to add a new question instead of add on to this one. (and when doing so, please expand on what 'the code crashes' means - are there exceptions?

Comment: Yes  , `xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File cannot be null` , and after hitting `open file` , the program shows that exception in `console` , while my program is running , then I pick my `xml` file , and then nothing happens , meaning the code doesn't parse the `xml` file as it usually does .

Comment: Note that frame itself will still be metal PLAF unless `updateComponentTree..` is called.  Might or might not be a problem here, I'm still not quite sure of the end result required.  +1 for noting *"I am sure that code was simply a self contained example"*.  Spot on.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare any Other class or use the JFrame class and delegate the Call to JFileChooser for there either by declaring new class/interface or over there itself , there is actually no sense of calling JFileChooser from Main method

Comment: If I remove the `main` from the code that was posted then it doesn't compile .

Comment: dont remove the code , I am just saying of not adding JFileChooser inside the Main class , create a new class from the UI Class and there you do the needful , why your main class should be responsible for creating FileCHooser