# JFileChooser opens the regular file browser instead of the expanded one

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel, jfilechooser

Following my previous two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907738/use-jfilechooser-without-using-a-main-declaration/10907832#comment14224031_10907832) and another [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900696/how-to-open-files-in-java-swing-without-jfilechooser/10901164#10901164), the following code 
opens the regular file browser instead of the expanded one:

```
public class GuiHandler extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    // data members
    private DataParser xmlParser = new DataParser();
    private File newFile;
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

    // more code 

    public void launchFileChooser() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    newFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            }
        });
    }

    // more code 

    private void XMLfilesBrowserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
        launchFileChooser();
        xmlParser.getNodeListFromFile(newFile);
        // here the code has the below problems
```

**Problems:**

1. The code opens a regular file browser when I hit a button to `open XML file`; it still allows me to pick a file.
2. It throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File cannot be null
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:198)
```

Why does it open the regular browser if `jfc` is a data member, and when it's a local
variable, the expanded one opens?

Comment: What happens if the user does not select a file in the dialog? `newFile` is only initialized if `jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`.

Comment: @GabrielNegut but that's still doesn't explain why the expanded file-browser doesn't open ...

Comment: I tried using the `JFileChooser` both as a local variable and a class member and it looks exactly the same to me...

Comment: @GabrielNegut: Windows platform . thanks .

Comment: If you get the Metal L&F when you use the chooser as a class variable, it's because you instantiate it before you set the system L&F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the regular versus expanded file chooser, make sure to call `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` before calling `new JFileChooser();`. Actually, unless you allow users to change the look and feel (L&F) during application execution, set the L&F close to the beginning of application execution, like in the `main` method, before creating any Swing components. From my experience, not doing so can cause some odd UI behavior.

When you have `JFileChooser` as a local variable in `launchFileChooser`, `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` is called before `new JFileChooser`. When `JFileChooser` is a class member variable (a.k.a. data member), `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` is called after `new JFileChooser`; in the latter case, the `JFileChooser` is created when an instance of `GuiHandler` is instantiated.

---

Concerning the `IllegalArgumentException` use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` in `launchFileChooser` instead of [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). Better yet, if you're sure `launchFileChooser` will always occur on the event dispatch thread, there's no need to call either `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

---

You also may want to use a file filter:

```
jfc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "xml"));
```

---

The following is an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the concepts discussed above:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class GuiHandler extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // call UIManager.setLookAndFeel early in application execution
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFrame frame = new GuiHandler();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final JFileChooser jfc;

    public GuiHandler() {
        this.jfc = new JFileChooser();
        this.jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        this.jfc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "xml"));

        final JButton button = new JButton("Open XML file");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xmlFilesBrowserActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        add(button);

        pack();
    }

    protected void xmlFilesBrowserActionPerformed() {
        final File xmlFile = getXmlFile();
        if (xmlFile != null) {
            System.out.println(xmlFile); // process XML file
        }
    }

    private File getXmlFile() {
        // At this point we should be on the event dispatch thread,
        // so there is no need to call SwingUtilities.invokeLater
        // or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait.
        if (this.jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return this.jfc.getSelectedFile();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , my friend, I've learned a lot from your example .

Comment: BTW , is it me or if the I hit `open XML` and then change my mind and hit `cancel` , then the exception comes back to life ... ?

Comment: @ron `jfc.getSelectedFile()` returns `null` on a cancel. Make sure to put `xmlParser.getNodeListFromFile(newFile);` inside an if statement, `if (newFile != null) { xmlParser.getNodeListFromFile(newFile); }`, to prevent the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'expanded one' but I assume you are referring to the file filter. In absence of any file filter, I'm guessing it's defaulting to showing all files. Try adding the following code before opening the dialog.

```
jfc.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File f){
        return  f.isDirectory() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return "XML File";
    }
})
```

Comment: No ,I didn't mean to the file filter . I meant that this link shows what I don't want :http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm , and this link shows what I do want http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FileDialogExample.htm . And I'm keep getting the `first` one instead of the `second` .

Comment: @ron There is a lot of stuff on those pages, exactly are you talking about? Are you talking about the lookAndFeel? Your question makes absolutely no reference to that.

Comment: I meant to the picture of each `url` on the first page .Both sites show a picture of a file browser . What I'm keep getting every time is the picture here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm . But I don't want that kind of file browser , I need this one , the one in the first page  :http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FileDialogExample.htm . Sorry if I mislead you .

Comment: Ok, so you are referring to the `LookAndFeel`, please mention that and you'll get much better answers. Anyway @creemama has a good answer for you. You need to set the look and feel before the Frame is initialized. Do you still have the null issue?

Comment: I've edited the entire code , took some time but it works - so first big thanks to the both of you .Second : when I hit the `open XML file` and choose a file , the code runs perfectly  , but when I hit the button and change my mind and hit `cancel` then I get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File cannot be null` , that's still won't let go . Any ideas how to take care of this ?

Comment: @ron I'm not sure what your new code looks like but the best thing to do is to check `xmlFile != null`, before you read the file. This is also in the accepted answer.